# limit of infinite sequence including $\sin(n!)$

Tags: calculus

What is the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ 2n \sin (n!)}{3n+5}$?

I tried to find two different subsequences with differnt limits.

Comment: It does not seem to exist.

Comment: Are the units degrees or radians? The answer is different depending on that.

Comment: Almost [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677719/the-limit-of-sinn)