# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n!)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is there a way to assess the convergence of the following series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n!)}{n}$$
From numerical estimations it seems to be convergent but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Are there infinitely many summands that are $\gt\frac{1}{2n}$? I don't think it converge..Does this help?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227574/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinnn?rq=1

Comment: If there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n!)=O(N^{1-\epsilon})$, then the series can be shown to converge by partial summation. I expect that $\sin(n!)$ is positive about as often as it is negative, and that $\sum_{n=1}^N\sin(n!)$ grows slowly, but I cannot see how to prove the necessary bound.

Comment: Also, Wolfram shows that the partial sums will all be greater than 1 eventually, so the series must diverge. Also, doesnt $\frac{-1}{n} \le \frac{\sin(n!)}{n} \le \frac{1}{n}$ get you any further?

Comment: For almost all $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n! \theta)}n $$ converges. However, it is a completely different story if $\theta=1$ belongs to the "almost all".

Comment: @i707107 is that a result from the theory of Fourier series ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yes It is. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem

Comment: I'm thinking use multiple angle formula for the sine and maybe Dirichlet test.

Comment: Can someone explain why we can't show that $\left | \frac{\sin(n!)}{n} \right | \leq \left | \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, implying the series is "bounded" by the alternating harmonic series?

Comment: @SpencerKraisler the RHS is equal to $\frac{1}{n}$. Without the absolute values, you actually have "$>$" for $n$ odd and $<$ for $n$ even

Comment: @SpencerKraisler You can do that, but your "upper bound" is not an absolutelly convergent series, so that would serve no purpose

Comment: It may help to know

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{n}}{n} = \frac{\pi - 1}{2} $$

@JulienRosen 
I expect you are correct about the sign of the $\sin$ term. It is most likely true in the above equality as well.

Comment: It must converge because sin(n˚) is 0 if n is a multiple of 360 and all factorials are from 6!.

Comment: A similar question has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677719/the-limit-of-sinn                                                                             The only difficulty is that neither 0*infinity nor o*infinity are defined.

Comment: Related: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248199/conditional-convergence-of-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sinpnn

Comment: The fact that there are infinitely many negative and positive terms seems to be a way to go. We do know that if the terms are perfectly alternate like a $(-1)^n$ it converges right? I think there is some sort of generalization of that

Comment: @TalesRickPerche unfortunately we do not know that $n! \pmod{2 \pi}$ is equidistributed (or even dense) in [0, 2pi) so we cannot prove convergence. I think this is basically an open problem...

Comment: Has there ever been a question with so many deleted answers?

Comment: @Thomas Even equidistribution is not strong enough to prove convergence. I once asked a question on that and was given a counter example which divergences. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488494/does-equidistribution-imply-convergence

Comment: It may help that $x!\approx\sqrt{2\pi x}(\frac{x}{e})^x$. The ratio of the two approaches 1 as $x\rightarrow\infty$. (Stirling's formula)

Comment: Perhaps Kolmogorov's Three-Series theorem or Kolmogorov Maximal Inequality will provide some  inspiration.  Certainly Byron Schmuland "Random Harmonic Series" has thought long and hard: http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/preprints/rhs.pdf

Comment: @SpencerKraisler I think it's hard to say much about the sign of  $sin(n!)$ in general if $n!$ is assumed to be an angle in radian measure.  It's highly improbable that it alternates in sign.

Comment: I know we can find an irrational number x in $(0,\pi)$ so that $sin(n!x)$ has same tail behavior as $sin(n!)$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a proof that the answer is (almost certainly) not provable using current techniques. We will prove that the series in fact diverges if $2\pi e$ is a rational number with a prime numerator. We first prove the following claims:

**Lemma 1.** If $p$ is an odd prime number and $S\subset \mathbb Z$ so that
$$\sum_{s\in S}e^{2\pi i s/p}\in\mathbb R,$$
then $\sum_{s\in S}s\equiv 0\bmod p$.

*Proof.* Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}$. We have
$$\sum_{s\in S}\zeta^s=\sum_{s\in S}\zeta^{-s},$$
since the sum is its own conjugate. As a result, since the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $\frac{\zeta^p-1}{\zeta-1}$, we see
$$\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}\bigg|\sum_{s\in S}\left(x^{p+s}-x^{p-s}\right),$$
where we have placed each element of $s$ in $[0,p)$. The polynomial on the left is coprime with $x-1$ and the polynomial on the right has it as a factor, so
$$\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}\bigg|\sum_{s\in S}\left(x^{p+s-1}+\cdots+x^{p-s}\right).$$
Now, the quotient of these two polynomials must be an integer polynomial, so in particular the value of the left-side polynomial at $1$ must divide the value of the right-side polynomial at $1$. This gives $p|\sum_{s\in S}2s,$ finishing the proof.

---

Define
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}.$$

**Lemma 2.** If $p$ is a prime number,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}a_n\equiv -1\bmod p.$$
*Proof.*
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}a_n
&=\sum_{0\leq k\leq n\leq p-1}\frac{n!}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{0\leq n-k\leq n\leq p-1}(n-k)!\binom n{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\sum_{n=j}^{p-1}n(n-1)\cdots(n-j+1)\\
&\equiv \sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}n(n-1)\cdots(n-j+1)\pmod p,
\end{align*}
where we have set $j=n-k$. The inside sum is a sum of a polynomial over all elements of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, and as a result it is $0$ as long as the polynomial is of degree less than $p-1$ and it is $-1$ for a monic polynomial of degree $p-1$. Since the only term for which this polynomial is of degree $p-1$ is $j=p-1$, we get the result.

---

Now, let $2\pi e = p/q$. Define $\mathcal E(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$ to map from $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, and note that $\mathcal E(x+\epsilon)=\mathcal E(x)+O(\epsilon)$. We have
\begin{align*}
\sin((n+p)!)
&=\operatorname{Im}\mathcal E\left(\frac{(n+p)!}{2\pi}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{Im}\mathcal E\left(\frac{qe(n+p)!}{p}\right).
\end{align*}
We will investigate $\frac{qe(n+p)!}{p}$ "modulo $1$." We see that
\begin{align*}
\frac{qe(n+p)!}{p}
&=q\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(n+p)!}{pk!}\\
&\equiv q\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{(n+p)!}{pk!}\pmod 1\\
&=O(1/n)+q\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{(n+p)!}{pk!}\\
&=O(1/n)+\frac qp\left[\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{(n+p)!}{k!}\pmod p\right].
\end{align*}
Now,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{(n+p)!}{k!}=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}\frac{(n+p)!}{(n+p-j)!}
&=\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}(n+p)(n+p-1)\cdots(n+p-j+1)\\
&\equiv \sum_{j=0}^{p-1}m(m-1)\cdots (m-j+1)\pmod p,
\end{align*}
where $m$ is the remainder when $n$ is divided by $p$. The terms with $j>m$ in this sum go to $0$, giving us
$$\sum_{j=0}^m \frac{m!}{(m-j)!}=a_m.$$
Putting this together, we see that
$$\sin((n+p)!)=\operatorname{Im}\mathcal E\left(\frac{qa_{n\bmod p}}p\right)+O\left(\frac 1n\right).$$
In particular, the convergence of our sum would imply, since the $O(1/n)$ terms give a convergent series when multiplied by $O(1/n)$, that
$$x_N=\operatorname{Im}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1n\mathcal E\left(\frac{qa_{n\bmod p}}p\right)$$
should converge. In particular, $\{x_{pN}\}$ must converge, which implies that
$$\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}\mathcal E\left(\frac{qa_m}p\right)$$
must be real (as otherwise the series diverges like the harmonic series). By Lemma 1, this implies that
$$\sum_{m=0}^{p-1}a_m=0\bmod p,$$
which contradicts Lemma 2.