# Does equidistribution imply convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory, equidistribution

The following is an interesting problem presented to this site which has yet to bet [solved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756038/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinnn): Does

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n!)}{n}$$

converge. While attempting this problem, I thought that proving the equidistribution of $n!$ modulo $2\pi$ would be sufficient for the original conjecture. For those who do not know, an sequence $a_n$ is said to be [equidistributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence) on a non-degenerate interval $[a,b]$ if

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{|\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}\cap [c,d]|}{n}=\frac{d-c}{b-a}$$

for all subintervals $[c,d]\subseteq [a,b]$. My thoughts then turned to the more general question: If $a_n$ is any sequence of real numbers such that $\mod(a_n,2\pi)$ is equidistributed over $[0,2\pi]$, does

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(a_n)}{n^\beta}$$

necessarily converge for $\beta>0$. Obviously, if $\beta>1$ then the series converges absolutely, so the interesting cases are $0<\beta<1$ and $\beta=1$ (although they might be the same case overall). One possible way forward is using [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl's_criterion): we know that if $a_n$ is equidistributed over $[0,2\pi]$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\sin(q a_j)}{n}=0$$

for all $q\in\mathbb{N}$. I'm not sure how this could be useful but it seems pretty close to the original sum. One result in favor of this conjecture is discussed on this [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248199/conditional-convergence-of-sum-n-geq-1-frac-sinpnn) post. That is, if $p(n)$ is any polynomial with rational coefficients, then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(p(n))}{n}$$

converges.

Comment: About $n!\mod{2\pi}$ being equidistributed: I don't think it is a solved problem, but this is interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01198

Comment: I don't think so either, but I realized that even if I did show that it was, then the question of convergence would still stand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Suppose we had equidistributed $(a_n)_n$ such that $\sum_{n \le t} \sin(a_n) \sim \frac{t}{\log t}$.

Then, for any $\beta \in (0,1]$, summation by parts gives $$\sum_{n \le N} \frac{\sin(a_n)}{n^\beta} = \frac{\sum_{n \le N} \sin(a_n)}{N^\beta}+\beta \int_1^N \frac{\sum_{n \le t} \sin(a_n)}{t^{1+\beta}}dt,$$ which diverges to $+\infty$ (the integral goes to $+\infty$; if $\beta < 1$, the first term does as well, and if $\beta = 1$, the first term goes to $0$).

We now construct such $(a_n)_n$. Fix $\theta = \sqrt{2}$ (any irrational would do). Let $b_n = n\theta$ mod $1$. Then $(b_n)_n$ is very equidistributed in that, for some absolute $C \ge 1$, $$\left|\sum_{n \le N} \sin(b_n)\right| \le C$$ for each $N \ge 1$ (recall $|\sum_{n \le N} e(n\theta)| \le \min(N,\frac{1}{||\theta||})$). Define $(a_n)_n = (b_1,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2},b_2,\frac{\pi}{2},b_3,\frac{\pi}{2},b_4,b_5,b_6,\dots)$, where we have inserted $\frac{\pi}{2}$'s into the sequence $(b_n)_n$ at prime indices. Then we have that $(a_n)_n$ is equidistributed, since we just modified an equidistributed sequence on a density $0$ set. And due to the last centered inequality (and the density of the prime numbers), we have $\sum_{n \le t} \sin(a_n) \sim \frac{t}{\log t}$.

---

The main reason the answer is "no" is that equidistribution is just a sublinear assumption on $\sum_{n \le t} \sin(a_n)$. If you wanted to define a sequence $(x_n)_n$ to be $\beta$-equidistributed if $\sum_{n \le N} \sin(qx_n) = o(N^\beta)$ (rather than $o(N)$) for each $q \in \mathbb{Z}$, then the answer would be "yes", as the summation by parts formula above shows.

One last thing I want to say, at the expense of being annoying. Weyl's criterion is really the converse of what you said. It is completely trivial to show that if a sequence $(x_n)_n$ is equidistributed, then $\sum_{n \le N} \sin(qx_n) = o(N)$ for each $q$. However, the quite remarkable thing is that if $\sum_{n \le N} \sin(qx_n) = o(N)$ and $\sum_{n \le N} \cos(qx_n) = o(N)$, then $(x_n)_n$ is equidstributed. This converse is really at the heart of fourier analysis, and is still quite magical to me.

Comment: Good answer. If you have the time, I would be very interested in more details of your analysis. I get the general gist of it but always enjoy a deeper dive into the details

Comment: @QC_QAOA Thanks for the response. I think all the details are added now. If you have a specific concern, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Very nice trick with the $\pi/2$ at prime indices. Would never have thought of that but it works out to such a great counterexample to my original conjecture.