# The limit of $(\sin(n!)+1)^{1/n}$ as n approaches infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, trigonometry, factorial

Calculate the limit

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sin(n!)+1)^{1/n}
$$

or prove that the limit does not exist.

This appeared as a problem in my mathematical analysis test, and the answer was that the limit exists and it was $1$. But later the teacher found a mistake in his proof and eventually removed the problem from the test. But I'm just curious. Does this problem have a certain answer?

The biggest question for me, is that I can't show that there does not exist any $n_0$ so that $\sin(n_0!)$ is close to $-1$ enough so that the original term might not converge. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is a similar question about $\cos(n!)$. The answer (as I understand it) is “we don't know.”

Comment: @MartinR we know $(\sin(n))_n$ is equidistributed, but do we know $(\sin(n!))_n$ is equidistributed? If it *isn't*, then we know for sure that the limit is $1$

Comment: @FShrike: The  problem of the density or lacunarity of the limit points of the sequence $\sin n!$ is probably as [hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8692/121671) as that of $\cos(n!)$.

Comment: @FShrike Please can you justify your claim? It seems wrong, or at best, unjustified to me. For example, it's not clear to me why we cannot have: $\ (\sin(n!))_n\ $ not equi-distributed and $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\sin(n!)+1)^{1/n}<1.$

Comment: I was being sloppy with my language, I meant one thing and wrote another @AdamRubinson . I was thinking: "... if $\sin(n!)$ is bounded away from $-1$, *then*..." but although: equidistributed --> not bounded away from $-1$, the converse fails! You are quite right, it's unjustified at present

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677719/the-limit-of-sinn?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45665/distribution-mod-1-of-factorial-multiples-of-real-numbers