# How do I find the limit of $\frac{n^3 \sin(n!)}{n^5 +1}$?

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate the following limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3\sin(n!)}{n^5+1}$$
I know the answer is zero and since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^5+1}=0$$
I want to show that $n^3\sin(n!)$ is bounded. I know for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$-1\leq\sin(n!)\leq1$$
But I don't know what can I do with $n^3$. When I tried to use WolframAlpha, it says
$$-69\leq n^3\sin(n!)\leq59$$
However, I have no idea how to get these values.

Comment: I’d try another method since $n^3 \sin(n!)$ is very likely not bounded. Can you compare the absolute value of the numerator and the denominator in your fraction?

Comment: Who knows how $n^3\sin(n!)$ is behaved. All you need is $-1\le\sin(n!)\le1$ though, since $\frac{n^3}{n^5+1}\to0$.

Comment: $\left|\frac{n^3\sin(n!)}{n^5+1}\right| \leq  \frac{n^3}{n^5+1} < \frac{n^3}{n^5} = \frac{1}{n^2} $

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted.

Comment: @TheoBendit No quality control on down-voting.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677719/27978. I suspect trying to show that $n^3 \sin (n!)$ is bounded would be difficult. See the related MO commentary.

Comment: I doubt Wolfram Alpha says $-69\leq n^3\sin(n!)\leq 59$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I agree that W|A must be used with caution. In this case however, I can't imagine what the OP input on W|A to get that result, because [it certainly doesn't give that bounds](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+n%5E3+sin%28n%21%29).

Comment: @jjagmath you can doubt about it, but yes, Wolfram Alpha says it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez fortunately I know what I'm doing and that's why I came here to see what's the problem.

Comment: @mvfs314 I shared the link where you can see it's not the case. Why don't you share the link of your search in Wolfram Alpha which says that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is show that $n^3\sin(n!)$ is bounded or you are trying to find the limit of $\frac{n^3\sin(n!)}{n^5+1}$ when $n{\to}$$\infty$ but,

if you are trying to find the limit of the above function then it's not the best way to show that $n^3 \sin(n!)$ is bounded instead you can show that $ \sin(n!)$  is bounded by one,

**i.e** $|\sin(n!)|\leq 1 $and $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^3}{n^5+1}=0$ so $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{n^3\sin(n!)}{n^5+1}=0$ .

Comment: If you precede trigonometric functions' names with a backslash, MathJax/LaTeX will know they are symbols. Then it will render them in an upright font and with spacing appropriate for functions' names, instead of an amorphous blob of italic, variable-like, letters. Compare `a sin x` → $a sin x$ vs. `a\sin x` → $a\sin x$.