# Divergence of the sequence $\sin(n!)$

Tags: analysis

Does the sequence $\sin(n!)$ diverge(converge)?

It seems the sequence diverges. I tried for a contradiction but with no success.
Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Does the sequence $\sin n$ diverge (converge)?

Comment: If $n!$ is in degrees (instead of radians), then $\sin(n!)=0$ for all $n\geq6$.

Comment: This looks harder than the divergence of $\sin n$. For one, if $\sin n!$ diverges, it follows automatically that $\pi$ is irrational, which is not an obvious fact. With $\sin n$, on the other hand, it is quite easy to prove divergence without knowing that $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: Same question for $\cos(n!)$, with some interesting commentary and answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/is-there-a-limit-of-cos-n

Comment: My suspicion is that this diverges but that that is not easy to show. (This assumes radians are used.)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether the parameter of $\sin$ is in radians or degrees. If in degree, $n!$ becomes multiple of 360 and after that function value will be zero, for all value of $n$.

In radians this will not happen as $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: I've up-voted this answer, but perhaps one should be explicit in saying that it is incomplete. It doesn't say whether the proposed sequence converges. But that is probably a very hard problem.