# How do I evaluate this sum :$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n!)}{\cos(n!)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I evaluate this sum :$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n!)}{\cos(n!)}$$

Note : I used many criterions of convergence to show if it converges but i

didn't up.

Thank you for any help .

Edit: Also asked at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209990/how-do-i-evaluate-this-sum-sum-n-0-infty-frac-sinn-cosn-if-i/209993#209993)

Comment: I see no reason to think this would converge. Is there a reason you'd think it might?

Comment: I have no idea, but it may help, maybe one of you will have a flash of genius the series of $$\sin^p\left(n!\pi e\right) $$ is convergent for $p\ge 1$

Comment: Turns out this is an [unsolved problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/is-there-a-limit-of-cos-n).

Comment: The length of the comment chain raised a system flag. I trimmed most of the comments. Zeraoulia rafik, if you ask the same question on many SE sites, please cross link them (and only do that in very exceptional circumstances).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, i asked the above question in MO after asking it here in SE

Comment: I did see that you linked to this question in MO. You could have also edited this version at that time.

Comment: In order for that to converge, you would need $n!$ to be a very good approximation of multiples of $\pi$, which I suppose is possible but highly unlikely and I expect someone would have noticed if it were true.