# For $x$ being irrational, why is $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}[\cos(n!\pi x)]^{2m}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

> Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. What is the value of $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \cos(n!\pi x) \right]^{2m}, \qquad (m,n \in \mathbb{N})$$

---

The answer given is $0$. I don't understand why it is so.

Comment: Related post: [Double limit of $\cos^{2n}(m! \pi x)$ at rationals and irrationals](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/264889). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bm%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5B%5Ccos(n!%5Cpi%20x)%5D%5E%7B2m%7D%24&p=1). Other [questions linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/264889) might be of interest, too.

Comment: @koolman, something is not right about your question: are you sure that it's $\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}$ and not $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty}$? Equivalently, are you sure that it's $[ \cos(n!\pi x) ]^{2m}$ and not $[ \cos(m!\pi x) ]^{2n}$? I bet you've inadvertently interchanged $m$ and $n$, because your question is not quite right.

Comment: @AlexM. This is the original question http://imgur.com/a/3XjRM

Comment: @AlexM. And how does that matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer has been rewritten thanks to the helpful criticism in Alex's comment.]

<s>The statement is wrong.</s> One has to take into consideration *first* the existence of the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(n!\pi x)^{2m},
$$
which is a highly non-trivial problem.

When $x=\dfrac{1}{\pi}$,
$
\cos(n!\pi x)=\cos(n!). 
$ But it seems that the existence of limit (which could be $1$)
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(n!)\qquad\text{(which could be $1$)},
$$
is an open problem (edited due to Fimpellizieri's comment) thanks to the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8692/9464) of this question: [Is there a limit of cos (n!)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8690/9464).

[Added: Interestingly, there is  related question in MO: [On the behaviour of $\sin(n!\pi x)$ when $x$ is irrational.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34369/14319)]

---

If you were to ask the double limit related to the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function) on the other hand:
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\big[\cos(m!\pi x)\big]^{2n}.
$$ 
you could read the accepted answer to this question:

[Double limit of $\cos^{2n}(m! \pi x)$ at rationals and irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264889/9464).

Note carefully (again, thanks to Alex's comment) that the order of taking the double limit is *different* from the one in your question:
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\big[\cos(m!\pi x)\big]^{2n}.
$$

Comment: How can we say this ??

Comment: Do you know for instance why $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2m}=0$?

Comment: No , I don't know that

Comment: ... Then you might either ask a follow-up question in a new post or look it up in your calculus textbook.

Comment: @AlexM.: I understand that you could have given your own answer without writing any comment to my previously stupid wrong hint. However you provided me a hint to learn something I didn't fully understand since I naively thought OP is asking about the Dirichlet function. Thank you very much and I apologize for my unreasonable complaint.

Comment: The linked answer does not state that $\cos(n!)\to1$, but rather that there is an (unlikely) scenario, which we do not yet know if it is or not true, in which that limit holds.

Comment: @Jack: Your answer doesn't clarify why the result should be $0$, as per the OP's claim. My belief is that the OP inadvertently interchanged $m$ and $n$. The fact that he has accepted your answer means nothing, because prior to this he had accepted another one. :)

Comment: @AlexM.: No. As I wrote in the answer, to the best of my knowledge, the existence of the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(n!\pi x)$ for $x$ being irrational in general is an open problem and thus it does not make sense to ask the double limit in OP without first giving the existence for *all* irrationals. That's it. In the second part of my answer, it is pointed out that OP might be asking the double limit regarding the Dirichlet function, which is a duplicate and I have given links to both the question and answer.

Comment: @Jack: True that. With so mant events happening on this page, I forgot about the second part of your post.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}j!^{-1},$ which is irrational, because $n!e\not \in \mathbb Z$ for any $n\in \mathbb N.$

For $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $$n!e=A_n+\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}n!/j!=A_n+B_n,$$ where $A_n\in \mathbb N$  and $B_n\in (0,1)$.By induction on $n,$ if $n$ is even then $A_n$ is odd, and if $n$ is odd then $A_n$ is even.

So for infinitely many $n$ we have $\cos (\pi n!e)=\cos \pi B_n$ and for infinitely many $n$ we have $\cos (\pi n!e)=-\cos \pi B_n.$

Therefore, since $\lim_{n\to \infty }B_n=0,$ the sequence $(\cos n!\pi e)_{n\in \mathbb N}$  has a  $\lim \sup$ of $+1$ and a $\lim \inf$ of $-1.$ Therefore  $\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(n!\pi e)$ does not exist.

Comment: @koolman, if I had been you, then this is the answer that I would have accepted.