# For which values of $ x$ we have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{\tan(n!)-n!}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, factorial

I have tried to to determine values of real $x$ for which $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{\tan(n!)-n!}$ converges but I can't ,Presumably  The set of values  $\{ n! \bmod 2\pi\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$  then $\tan(n!)$ will be large arbitrarily ,infinitely often , and the difference $\tan(n!)-n!$ would be probably small  however I don't know anything about limit of the fraction $\frac{\tan(n!)}{n!}$ for large $n$, And I have used Stiriling formula but it weren't helpful , This really forbide me to determine how $x$ values should be to get the titled series converge , then my question is :

> > **Question:**
> >     For which values of real number  $x$ we have $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{\tan(n!)-n!}$ converges ? We may avoid trivial case $x=0$

Comment: "The set of values  $\{ n! \bmod 2\pi\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$ " You'd have to prove that, first.

Comment: Considering that [we don't know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8690/is-there-a-limit-of-cos-n) whether $\cos n!$ converges or not, this may be a hard problem.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, I think also because tan( n!) depend to irrationality measure of pi

Comment: If at all the series converges, then clearly then we must have $0<x<1.$

Comment: The copy of that question is already posted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/361945/51189)